# std::map::operator[] behaving strangely

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I don't know what I did wrong but I have a map:

```
std::map<std::pair<ID, ID>, std::queue<Datum>> readQueues;
```

Everything's fine until I call `readQueues[std::make_pair(src, dst)];` and then I get an error that my arguments do not match the arguments of the function. The funny thing is that the whole thing works with `std::map::find` and `map::at` with the exact same arguments... Any ideas?

Comment: What's the type of `src` and `dst`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscript-operator of `map` cannot work for `const` maps (or const references to maps for that matter). That is because it may actually change the `map` - recall that

```
m[a] = 7;
```

will work even if `a` is not present in `m`. In that case `a` is inserted in to `m` first. Thus the semantic involves a potential modification, and that is exactly what `const` member functions shall not do.

You can instead use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) which will return an iterator. In particular, `find` returns `end()` when the passed key is not contained yet.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator[]` is non-`const`, so you cannot use it when you only have a const-reference to your map, unlike `find` and `at`.

Comment: @lightxbulb: The map itself mustn't be const. The `[]`-operator *inserts* new elements into the map.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment, because Columbo actually answered the question faster than I could type.